# download pdf generated by jspdf with non-default title

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

This is my first time using `jspdf` so please forgive me if this is a basic problem.

I have successfully generated the pdf, opening it in a new tab on my browser, with correct filename displayed on topleft. However, when I try to download the file, the filename is not the one thats shows there but the default "download.pdf" no matter what file it is.

I figure out that the simplest solution is

```
const doc = new jsPDF();
// add some content here.
doc.save("the real file name i want.pdf");
```

which saves the file locally with no issue, however, I still want to see the file on the browser first and then decide whether to download it or not......

I did some research around, these posts are relevant but they either do not directly solve my issue or seems kind of outdated.....

[How to open generated pdf using jspdf in new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17739816/how-to-open-generated-pdf-using-jspdf-in-new-window)

[Download PDF file using jsPDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31818648/download-pdf-file-using-jspdf)

So far, my best approaches were:

```
doc.output('dataurlnewwindow'); // open in a new tab but save with default name
```

```
window.open(doc.output('bloburi', {filename: `${name} pos.pdf`}), '_blank') // open in a new tab but save with blob name
```

Any help will be appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: Not possible https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63329692/is-there-a-way-to-set-a-file-name-when-jspdf-output

Answer (score 0):

[If you create an object URI, the filename can't be altered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66042121/8384910) so you could instead use a pdf viewer library to display it inline so that you can [alter the download button to work](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/10435) or upload it to some server so that you can customise the name.